# How to input a point coordinates in PyQGIS?

Tags: python, gis, qgis

I want to write a script that will prompt the user for X and Y coordinates. These coordinates will add a point to an existing shape file. Also, which function call should I use to get these coordinates?

```
vectorLyr = QgsVectorLayer("D:/Projekty/qgis_projekt/forty922.shp", "Forty", "ogr")
vpr = vectorLyr.dataProvider()
x = QInputDialog.getDouble(None, 'input', 'Insert x: ')
y = QInputDialog.getDouble(None, 'input', 'Insert y: ')
pnt = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(x,y))
f = QgsFeature()
f.setGeometry(pnt)
vpr.addFeatures([f])
vectorLyr.updateExtents()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([vectorLyr])
```

Input window works fine, but Python Console throws this statement

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:/users/hubi/appdata/local/temp/tmpxkrjpx.py", line 5, in <module>
    pnt = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(x,y))
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QgsPoint(): too many arguments
  QgsPoint(QgsPoint): argument 1 has unexpected type 'tuple'
  QgsPoint(float, float): argument 1 has unexpected type 'tuple'
  QgsPoint(QPointF): argument 1 has unexpected type 'tuple'
  QgsPoint(QPoint): argument 1 has unexpected type 'tuple'
```

It works well when I'm adding a constant numbers to my pnt variable.

```
pnt = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(361637,501172))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the following line in your stacktrace:

`QgsPoint(QgsPoint): argument 1 has unexpected type 'tuple'`

The python is interpreter is telling you that you are getting a tuple as input when you are expecting an integer. Change the code to the following:

```
vectorLyr = QgsVectorLayer("D:/Projekty/qgis_projekt/forty922.shp", "Forty", "ogr")
vpr = vectorLyr.dataProvider()
x = QInputDialog.getDouble(None, 'input', 'Insert x: ')
y = QInputDialog.getDouble(None, 'input', 'Insert y: ')
pnt = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(x[0],y[0]))
f = QgsFeature()
f.setGeometry(pnt)
vpr.addFeatures([f])
vectorLyr.updateExtents()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([vectorLyr])
```

Hope this helps!